# "(#10) Application does not have permission for this action" when creating a page or changing a page's cover image

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

"(#10) Application does not have permission for this action" when creating a page, changing a page's cover image, etc.  Posting is working fine.

I'm new to using the Graph API. Got the token stuff working sufficiently to add/"feed" a post to various pages without too much trouble. I then tried some other things and get the error: "(#10) Application does not have permission for this action"
I am getting this when trying to change a page's cover, create a page, etc. I can post messages to paged through facebook.com .
The app is in developer mode.

Here is a call to create a page that generates the error:
https://graph.facebook.com/10216XXXXXX509/accounts with the data {'name': 'XXpage nameXX', 'category_enum': 'EDU_SITE', 'access_token': 'EA...ZD', 'about': 'This page presents ...'}

And another to change a pages cover:
https://graph.facebook.com/27717XXXXXX336 with the data: {'cover_id': '236795307270833', 'offset_x': 50, 'offset_y': 39, 'access_token': '...'}

I think I have the correct access_token and page ids because I use them successfully in the API to "feed" a new post onto a page.

Sorry if this is a simple problem. I have spent a lot of time trying to resolve this permission problem Googling around, YouTube searching & viewing, and using the facebook api docs (https://developers.facebook.com/…/graph-api/using-graph-api/), without luck.

Thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you read the documentation for the APIs that you are trying to use to see what permissions are needed?

Comment: Yes.  The docs to which I referred are https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/accounts/#Creating

The app is in test mode, so I think I do not yet need approval.  The token I am using has the appropriate permissions (manage_pages and publish_pages).  I must be missing something, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Is the user a test user like the documentation say? The app being in test mode and the user being a test user are two completely different things

Comment: The user is admin, which I think includes the privileges of test user.  This application is basically a server that moves some data from one repository into FB posts.  Depending on what the server finds when running it might want to create a new FB page and put posts on it.

Comment: The user needs to be a test user. The create Page API is only for testing. No real users will be able to access the Page you created using the API.

Comment: Oh.  Where does one learn that?  I did not see it in the documentation.  So, via the API I can not create a page for use by typical users.  Hmmm, gotta rethink some things then
WizKid - thank you for you help.  Do you learn this stuff by trial and error, or have I missed some great source of information?

Comment: The documentation say that only a test user can create a page.

Comment: This comment from @WizKid is the right answer! I just created a test user with required permissions and then it worked.